# How to open a pdf file in a new window after rendering it through Shiny in R

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to make a shinny app that downloads data from a server, selects a rmarkdown report to run, runs said report, and opens the pdf file that was just rendered in a new window. I was able to do all of that except for the last part.
How can I open the pdf file that was newly rendered using Shiny?

Here is my ui:

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Input Parameters"),
  
  column(4, wellPanel(
    dateInput('date',
              label = 'Select the Start Date of the Report:',
              value = Sys.Date(),
              format = "dd-M-yy"),
    
    dateInput('date2',
              label = paste('Select the End Date of the Report:'),
              value = Sys.Date(),
              format = "dd-M-yy"),
    
    selectInput("report_name", "Select Report to Process:", 
                c("Report1" = "running_report",
                  "Report2" = "jogging_report")),
    
    
    
    actionButton("button", "Run Report")
    
  )),
  
  column(6,
         verbatimTextOutput("dateText"),
         verbatimTextOutput("dateText2")
  )
  
)
```

And this is my server

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
 
  

     
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      
      if(input$report_name == "Report1"){
        
        file_location <- "notebooks/running_report.Rmd"
        print(file_location)
        
      }else if(input$report_name == "Report2"){
        
        file_location <- "notebooks/jogging_report.Rmd"
        print(file_location)
        
      }
      
      #Formating current date as a title
      title_date <- format(as.Date(Sys.Date(), "%d-%m-%y"),"%m_%d_%Y")
      
      #Formating the title using the input
      
      title <- substring(input$report_name, regexpr("/", input$report_name) + 1)
      title <- strsplit(title, "[.]")[[1]][1]
      title <- paste0( title, '_',title_date, sepp='')
      
      detach("package:kableExtra", unload=TRUE)
      
      rmarkdown::render(file_location ,output_file = paste0( title, '_','module_report',title_date, sepp=''), envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))     
      
      detach("package:kableExtra", unload=TRUE)
      
      filename = paste0( title, '_','report_name',title_date,'.pdf', sepp='')
      
      content = function(file) file.copy(filename, file, overwrite = TRUE)
      
      
      
      print(title_date)
      print(title)
      
      
      
      
    }) 
  
  
  
  
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider opening the PDF with acrobate reader with the following code :

```
system2(command = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Acrobat Reader DC/Reader/AcroRd32.exe", args = "C:/mypdf.pdf")
```